# Python square wave function - What is going on here?

Tags: python, audio, numpy, pygame

I have a function for creating a square wave in python and I can't seem to get a sound out of it, but when I change this:

```
value = state * volume
s.append( [value, value] )
```

to this:

```
value = state * volume
s.append( [0, value] )
```

I get a sound, but it is of a frequency much higher than the 130.81 frequency I intended it to produce. Here is the full code:

```
def SquareWave(freq=1000, volume=10000, length=1):

    num_steps = length * SAMPLE_RATE
    s = []

    length_of_plateau = SAMPLE_RATE / (2*freq)

    counter = 0
    state = 1

    for n in range(num_steps):

        value = state * volume
        s.append( [value, value] )

        counter += 1

        if counter == length_of_plateau:
            counter = 0
            state *= -1

    return numpy.array(s)

def MakeSound(arr):
    return pygame.sndarray.make_sound(arr)

def MakeSquareWave(freq=1000):
    return MakeSound(SquareWave(freq))
```

The block of code for calling these function is as follows:

```
elif current_type == SQUARE_WAVE_TYPE:

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:

                #lower notes DOWN

                if event.key == K_z:
                    print current_type, 130.81
                    #current_played['z'] = MakeSineWave(80.81)
                    current_played['z'] = MakeSquareWave(130.81)
                    current_played['z'].play(-1)

                elif event.key == K_c:
                    print current_type, 180.81
                    #current_played['c'] = MakeSineWave(80.81)
                    current_played['c'] = MakeSquareWave(180.81)
                    current_played['c'].play(-1)
```

Can anyone see why this is happening? Is this square wave function actually correct?

Comment: What is the value of `counter` vs. `length_of_plateau` inside the loop, can you debug the code and find a concrete example of what the value of those two are?

Comment: Use `print value` to see what values you have.

Comment: The reason I ask is that I suspect the `length_of_plateau` is a floating point value, whereas `counter` is an integer, and thus the chance of them becoming equal at any point when frequency is 130.81, is none at all, or perhaps once-in-a-blue-moon is more correct. In any case, please verify the values of those variables and see if it matches what I say here.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen you are right, it has to be (for example) `int()` in `length_of_plateau = int( SAMPLE_RATE / (2*freq) )`

Comment: Though just casting to int will not be right either. I suspect that the code should check if `counter` is *greater than* some value, which is initially set to be the length of the plateu, and then each time it is, you increase that value by the length of the plateu. In this way you would smooth out rounding errors over time. If you simply cast to int you have not gained a 130.81 frequency (over time), but a permanent rounding error.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen good point

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - make your comment an answer.

Comment: @mtrw Posted it as an answer with code to boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your problem is most likely because you're not taking floating point values correctly into account.

Take this comparison:

```
if counter == length_of_plateau:
```

This compares `counter`, an integer, with `length_of_plateau`, a floating point value.

`length_of_plateau` came from this assignment:

```
length_of_plateau = SAMPLE_RATE / (2*freq)
```

With a frequency of 130.81, and a sample rate of 44100 (I'm guessing here, you're not posting what the value of SAMPLE_RATE is), you get this:

```
length_of_plateau = 168.565094412
```

So, an integer will never be equal to that value.

Instead, here's what I would do:

```
state = 1
next_plateau_end = length_of_plateau

counter = 0
for n in range(num_steps):
    value = state * volume
    s.append( [value, value] )

    if counter >= next_plateau_end:
        counter -= length_of_plateau
        state *= -1
    counter += 1
```

Instead of resetting `counter` to 0 each time, instead we're subtracting the length of the plateau (which is a floating point value). This means that the rounding error that was introduced in the original code will be smoothed out over time.

Comment: I'm not altogether sure what the point of adding `[value, value]` is, if this adds two values to the output you're not getting the correct frequency, but you're the best judge of what is correct here. I'm 100% sure that the floating point problem is what is making the program generate the incorrect waveform though.

Comment: Nice answer, you could also write a function that would compute the error at a given sampling rate.

Comment: I would make one change to this - instead of `next_plateau_end += length_of_plateau`, I would do `n -= length_of_plateau`. The reason for this is if this ever gets ported to C, then `n` will be a finite integer type. If that finite integer type is 16-bit or 32-bit, as currently written it is entirely possible `n` will overflow in a reasonable time (At 44100 Hz, 2^31 samples ~= 13.5 hours). At the overflow, one cycle will get distorted.

Not that that I've _ever_ made this mistake, oh no.

Comment: While I won't change `n`, I understand what you're saying, so let me edit the answer.

Comment: It would be preferable to round length_of_plateau to the nearest integer rather than trying to "smooth" the error out over time. Think about what the fft would look like.

Comment: Digital sound is imprecise to begin with, but I don't have enough experience to say what is better or not. You will not get 130.81 frequency by rounding the plateau permanently though, but as I said, I don't know enough about this to say which will sound better or more correct. I think the OP should decide that.